# Which LEGO vehicle has 1x 50373 and 2x 30165 red bricks

Tags: set-identification

I have a vehicle that we previously built with, ostensibly, the paper book instructions. Lo and behold, they are MIA. The vehicle is mostly intact and mostly red, so I'm betting it's fire or rescue. There are some unique bricks on it: 2 pieces of red [30165 2x2x1 curved doule slope brick](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=30165#T=C&C=5) and a *really* unique red [50373 3x4 wedge brick](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=50373#T=C&C=5).

[image: curved double slope brick][image: 3x4 wedge brick]

Anyone have any ideas what it might be? The front end is definitely a truck but I'm not sure how wide it's supposed to be or tire size, as hurricane five-year-old decided they needed to go. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Including a picture of the vehicle you're looking at would help increase the level of certainty in the answer(s).

Comment: It seems I mistakenly edited the question and assumed that the wedge brick was red, since the wording led me to believe that. I hope @DavidDesautel can clarify the colour of the wedge brick, please?

Answer (score 6):

From your description, it seems most likely to be 10715 [Bricks on a Roll](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=10715-1). There was also a Wal-Mart edition. The only other set which has both items is 76054-1 Batman: Scarecrow Harvest of Fear, but its 50373 is blue; the original question implied it was red, but it got edited to say it **definitely** is red.

[image: 10715]

Comment: Part 2399 is similar, but has no sets on BrickLink with both it (in any color) and at least two 30165 pieces.

Comment: 10715-1/2 seems more likely given (a) the op mentions the front end definitely resembles a truck (not a tractor), (b) in 76054-1 the 50373 part is in blue and is not part of the same vehicle and (c) in 76054-1, there are 3 red 30165 parts (not 2) - although 1 could presumably have gone missing.

Comment: I agree - I'll delete the reference to Batman. The question text explicitly says all 3 parts are red, which I must have missed.

Comment: Oh, wait! The original question did **not** actually say 50373 was red - that was put in with an edit afterward. Edits should not change the question!